# Do not load the related Landscape/Portrait layout on rotation

Tags: java, android, eclipse, user-interface, android-fragments

I am having a very disturbing trouble with my Android application. I am using `Fragments`. Each fragment contains a seperate XML file for Portrait UI and Landscape UI.

If I move from fragment '`InputFragment`' to fragment '`OutputFragment`', and if I rotate the device now, the Fragment get changed to '`InputFragment`' !! Which means, application is going back to the previous fragment  on rotation! But, this is not what should happen. If I rotate the device once it is in Portrait, then it should call the Landscape UI of the same fragment and wise versa.

Following is the code. I only display the structure of the code, because all other are declaration of variables and assigning values etc.

**InputFragment.java**

```
public class InputFragment extends Fragment {

    //Declaring variables. CODE REMOVED




    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        //Intializing instance variables. CODE REMOVED

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.input, container,false);



        restoreStates(savedInstanceState);

        return view;

    }

    //This method will save the instances
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceStateBundle) 
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceStateBundle);

        try{

        }
        catch(NullPointerException e)
        {

        }
    }

    //This method will restore the instances
    @Override 
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceStateBundle)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceStateBundle);

        if(savedInstanceStateBundle!=null)
        {
        }
    }

    //Action Listener for the Submit Bar
    private class SubmitButtonAction implements OnClickListener
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                //Put the JSON. Calling to the JSON handling class. CODE REMOVED


            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            }

            Fragment frag = new OutputFragment();

            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();   
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, frag);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();



        }

    }



    private void restoreStates(Bundle savedInstanceStateBundle)
    {
        if(savedInstanceStateBundle!=null)
        {

        }
    }




}
```

**OutputFragment.Java**

```
public class OutputFragment extends Fragment implements AsyncResponse{

    //Delclaring variables. CODE REMOVED


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        //Intializing instance variables. CODE REMOVED
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.output, container,false);


        return view;

    }


    //ActionListener for the manual back button
    private class BackButtonAction implements OnClickListener
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager(); 
            fm.popBackStackImmediate();

        }

    }


    @Override
    public void processFinish(String output) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("OUTPUT_FRAGMENT", output);

        try {





            progressDialog.dismiss();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.Window;

    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            Fragment frag = new InputFragment();

            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();    
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, frag);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }



}
```

**Manifest File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxx.xxx"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/xxx_logo"
        android:label="@string/xxx"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="com.xxx.xxx.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenLayout|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/xxx" >

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.xxx.xxx.SplashScreen"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenLayout|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/xxx" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

After searching for hours, I found a solution to stop this issue. That is, adding the code `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenLayout|orientation|screenSize"` to the Manifest file.

Now, the Fragment do not move to the previous fragment on Rotation, but, it do not load the Other layout as well! Which means, it do not load the 'Landscape' UI if I rotate the phone from Portrait to Landscape and wise versa! It simply tries to adjust itself to the view and it is not good because the images and everything get displayed badly without loading the other related UI. What has happened here?

Comment: your layout doesn't not change because you used `android:configChanges` attr which basicaly is made for preventing the layouts to recreate on rotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After rotation your Activity is recreated and its `onCreate()` method is called.
What you want to do is to check if the activity is launched for the first time and only then replace your fragment wiht `InputFragment`. On Activity first creation savedInstanceState is null so you can do something like this:

```
if(savedInstanceState == null) {
    // replace fragment 
}
```

**EDIT:**

This is how your `onCreate()` in Activity should look:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            Fragment frag = new InputFragment();

            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();    
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, frag);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }
```

Now, on orientation change activity wont replace your fragment and you don't need to set any attrs in Manifest

Comment: Not in fragment, in your activitys `onCreate` method. Put the FragmentTransaction code there. And remember to remove `configChanges` attr in Manifest

Comment: This seems to be working, but it contains an issue. The "public void processFinish(String output)" method starts running. This is a call back method. InputFragment process a network operation and while doing that, it move to the OutputFragment to show the results. Output fragment displays a progress dialog in "processFinish()" and once the operation is done, it close the dialog and display the result, which means the image. Here, it just display the progress dialog (which is not needed) and do nothing.